# Ubuntu Bacula backup chinese (unicode) files

Tags: bacula, unicode

My bacula 5.0.2 on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS is unable to backup chinese/unicode text files. Not a permission issue because english text files like test.txt have no issues. Does anyone have any idea how?

The error message is 
Could not stat "/home/it/group/July/??.txt": ERR=No such file or directory